# Print multiple transfer order's Picking list (WMSPickinglist_OrderPick) report in ax 2012

Tags: reporting-services, report, axapta, x++, sqlreportingservice

My requirement is, I want to print Multiple Transfer order Picking list report (WMSPickingList_OrderPick).
Navigation : Inventory and warehouse management > Periodic > Transfer update > Picking list.
when I select multiple Transfer order's picking list for printing, only one report is printed other are shown on screen.
how can I acheive my requiment.
thanks

I tried to change in system classes InventTransferMulti, inventTransferMultiPick, InventTransferUpdPick,
but I don't want this change because it's system classes.

Comment: Do you have any code you've attempted to write?